# Turn off error and access logs for one virtual host

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, virtualhost

If I dont set a error log inside a virtual host it will default to the default error/access log. Is there a way to turn this off for one virtual host?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Within your `<VirtualHost>` block for the vhost in question you can configure the logs to be sent to /dev/null

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName nologserver.tld

     ErrorLog /dev/null
     CustomLog /dev/null common
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Would this work on Windows, too?

Comment: @UweKeim No, I'm looking for a Windows solution as well...

Comment: What does the `common` part do? Why does the CustomLog need to be `/dev/null common` rather than just `/dev/null`?

Comment: @Pikamander2 the documentation will reveal all and is your friend

Comment: @user9517 - I don't see the "common" keyword listed anywhere. Which page of documentation contains info about it?

Answer (score 0):

Change /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/other-vhosts-access-log.conf to following:

```
ErrorLog /dev/null

CustomLog /dev/null common
```

Comment: I get the following error when restarting apache after this change: Syntax error on line 71 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/example.com:
CustomLog takes two or three arguments, a file name, a custom log format string or format name, and an optional "env=" clause (see docs)

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu

```
sudo a2disconf other-vhosts-access-log
```